# How to convert date to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, casting

I want to convert dateformat to mm/dd/yyyy.  Whatever dateformat is coming in textbox, I want to convert it into mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Exactly what is the source "dateformat" you're dealing with?

Comment: Do you want "mm/dd/yyyy" or US format, perhaps based on the user's locale?

Comment: You never cease to amaze me with your incessant questions about date formats. They all look the same to me. Now, whenever I see a new "convert date to XXXXX format" question, I know it's going to be ramyatk06 !

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get it into a datetime object.  The most common standards work via:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
```

If you expect a freaky format, you still have to know what format it is:

```
DateTime x;
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "YYddd", out x);
```

Then simply output the data:

```
string date = x.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

But you really need to enforce your formatting using regex, validators, scout's honor - *something*.

Comment: That's the wrong signature.  DateTime.TryParseExact (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) returns a boolean and takes a DateTime out reference.

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "YYddd", out x); is showing following error.
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParseExact' accepts this number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721%28VS.71%29.aspx) for full details.
You will need to [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28VS.80%29.aspx) the input to a DateTime object and then convert it to any text format you want.

If you are unsure what format you may be getting, maybe it is a good idea to restrict the user to a single format (using validation or better yet a date picker).