# Regular Expression for mm/dd/yyyy in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

What would be the regular expression for mm/dd/yyyy in asp.net with month ,date and year validation?

Comment: Why regex? Why not a DateTime Field?

Comment: Why using a regular expression to validate a datetime in the first place?

Comment: Why not even googleing it? http://forums.asp.net/t/1524101.aspx/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date to mm/dd/yyyy format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954325/how-to-convert-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/
```

check [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/regular-expression-to-validate-date-in.html)

Comment: This will treat 31-02-yyyy and 30-02-yyyy as valid including non leap years' 29-02-yyyy

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include a description here.